# Multiple storage types with paperclip gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, paperclip

Is it possible to have multiple storage types with the [Paperclip](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip) gem?

I need to be able to POST a file that a user has uploaded. Currently I am using :s3 storage option. This seems like there is extra bandwidth up and down that could be avoided if I put the file in `:rails_root/tmp`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the gem '[paperclip-storage-tmp](https://github.com/exviva/paperclip-storage-tmp)'

> his gem allows you to configure Paperclip 2.x to use your temporary directory to store the attachments.

once you have it on your project this you can do something like

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_attached_file :avatar, storage: :tmp
end
```